# Zombiejs browser.text method returning entire document

Tags: node.js, zombie.js

Like it says in the title:

```
zombie = require "zombie"
should = require "should"
browser = new zombie.Browser();

describe "index", ->
  describe "herp derp", ->
    it "should display room input", (done) ->
      browser.visit "http://localhost:3000/", (err, browser) ->
        if err
          throw err.message
        browser.text('title').should.equal 'Welcome to Test!'
        done()
```

browser.text('title') returns the html of the entire page.  This happens for any element I attempt to select.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried opening up another URL? If so, do you get the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

What happens, if you change your code to this:

```
Browser = require "zombie"
should = require "should"


describe "index", ->
  describe "herp derp", ->
    it "should display room input", (done) ->
      Browser.visit "http://localhost:3000/", (err, browser) ->
        if err
          throw err.message
        browser.text('title').should.equal 'Welcome to Test!'
        done()
```

?